# Why isn't the std::showpos method working properly?

Tags: c++

I am a naive C++ learner, currently doing IO manipulations.
I have a code below which uses std::showbase, std::showpos and std::uppercase.
showbase and uppercase are working fine. But I am not getting the desired output for showpos.
Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int a = 26;
        cout << std::showbase;
        cout << std::oct;
        cout << a << "\n";
        cout << std::hex;
        cout << a << "\n";
        cout << std::showpos;
        cout << a << "\n";
        cout << std::uppercase;
        cout << a << "\n";
        return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
032
0x1a
0x1a
0X1A
```

Shouldn't output's *3rd line* and *4th line* produce a "+" prefix?

Comment: I wouldn't expect a sign to show for hex numbers. That representation has no concept of neither negative or positive. Same as binary.

Comment: wait, how would you like to print the value `int a = -1` in hex? Because to me, that **must** be `0xffffffff`. I'm not looking at hex to learn something about how the absolute of a number is represented as hex, but to learn something about how the bytes in the machine look like.

Comment: @heapunderrun thanks, I think that qualifies as original to this duplicate :)

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes, a duplicate, but I don't have enough reputation points to close this myself.

Comment: I see, @heapunderrun; but you're on your way. By the way, you can always already *Flag* (eponymous link under the question) a question as "needs improvement" -> "Duplicate". That can be quite helpful, because the high-rep users get nagged to work through a review queue, where they then see your helpful flag of "oh yeah, that's been answered before".

Comment: Yeah, I guess I asked it again. Thanks MarcusMüller heapunderrun